# Double Progress Bars for Jupyter/PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I've some code that needs to run over two loops of not insignificant length. So what I'd like to be able to do is have two progress bars; one for each loop.

```
for _ in tqdm(range(10)):
    for _ in tqdm(range(100)):
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

I thought that `tqdm` supported this, and it appears that it does if I run in IPython. However, if I run inside a Jupyter notebook, or in PyCharm, instead of updating the bar(s) after each loop it prints each update on a new line.

I assume that this is something specific to the way that printing works. Has anyone figured out a way to make multiple progress bars work inside a notebook, or in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently there's a `leave` argument.

For Jupyter noteboooks:

```
import time

from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

for _ in tqdm(range(10)):
    for _ in tqdm(range(1000), leave=False):
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Otherwise:

```
import time

from tqdm import tqdm

for _ in tqdm(range(10)):
    for _ in tqdm(range(1000), leave=False):
        time.sleep(0.01)
```